# How to perform MITM for Facebook Android app using Charles proxy?

Tags: facebook, ssl-certificate, android-facebook, sslhandshakeexception, charles-proxy

I've been struggling to perform Man in the Middle (MITM) attack for Facebook android app with Charles Proxy. I'm able to do it for other applications such as Yahoo Mail,Twitter etc. When I try to do it for Facebook app I'm getting the following error.

> SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: unknown_ca

Help me to solve this:

[image]

Comment: I also want to know if there's still a way to view network traffic from the facebook app ios/android...

Comment: It likely uses certificate pinning.  You might try this strategy: http://blog.opensecurityresearch.com/2013/11/patching-android-application-to-bypass.html  Although I'm not sure if this will work.